# How do I make one form load before the other in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms in a visual C# forms application. I want to load one form before the other, however it automatically loads form1 first (even though that's the one I want to have load second).

How do I change that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at `Program.cs`, which will probably have something like:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Change that to start with the second form.

Answer (score 5):

you need to modify `Program.cs`
here is sample

```
  static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

it is loading Form1.cs by default you can set to load any form

If i want to launch `MyForm.cs` then i would change it like

```
Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project's properties, you can change wich form is loaded at startup. If I remember correctly, in the *Project Explorer* dock, if you right-click a form, you can choose the option **Set as startup object** (or was that only for *"sub-projects"*?).

Comment: Wrong it does not happen in this fashion .This is if there are more than one project in a solution and you select one from many to start when the program loads